¿Cual es la diferencia entre Compilation Fails y Exception Runtime en JAVA?
Debido a que he visto estos conceptos en algunas preguntas de examen Java y en otros ejercicios mis preguntas serian:
¿Cuál es la diferencia entre Runtime Exception y Compilations Fails? y ¿Como se identifican al momento de ejecutar el codigo?
Se los agradecería mucho si me lo pudieran explicar, gracias.

Compilation fails significa que tienes un error de sintaxis en el código, por lo que no puede ser ejecutado. Exception runtime significa que el código no tiene errores de sintaxis (compila bien), pero durante la ejecución realizas alguna instrucción errónea (dividir por cero, por ejemplo), lo que impide seguir ejecutando.

Los fallos de compilación no son sólo de sintaxis, sino cualquier otro que el compilador sea capaz de detectar, por ejemplo, errores de comprobación de tipos. O fallos del mismo compilador (muy raros, pero posibles). En esta pregunta hay varias respuestas que aclaran con detalle tu duda.
